# saber la cantidad de archivos que tiene un input file con js

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito saber la cantidad de archivos que tiene un input file en un script js, necesito hacerlo con document.getelementbyid para mi proyecto
el codigo es el siguiente pero me retorna undefined

```js
function contarImgs() {
  alert(document.getElementById('imagen').files.lenght);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input type="file" id="imagen" name="imagen[]" onchange="contarImgs()" multiple>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un error de escritura en `length`

```js
function contarImgs() {
  alert (document.getElementById('imagen').files.length)
   
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="file" id="imagen" name="imagen[]" onchange="contarImgs()" multiple>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Con Jquery ejemplo:

```js
console.log($("#imagen").get(0).files.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input type="file" id="imagen" name="imagen[]" multiple>
</form>
```

Comment: Realmente esto no parece una respuesta. ¿ Usted resolvería el con estos datos ? Esta bien que quiera ayudar @DanielDavila pero hay que hacerlo un poco mejor. Le aconsejo que repase [como dar una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y aproveche para repasar el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), encontrara respuestas a casi todo. Esto le ayudara a conseguir reputación y ayudara a otros usuarios.

Comment: he editado tu respuesta para que contenga el html, asegurate de que es asi como lo pretendias y en dado caso explica su funcionamiento